# Bootstrap Dropdown menu issue on mobile

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I will need some help with the menu showing on mobile. When the STORE menu is clicked on mobile version it does not expand and instead closes the general menu. Here is the link of the web page. Any help will be appreciated.

`<body>` looks like

```
<!-- The #page-top ID is part of the scrolling feature - the data-spy and data-target are part of the built-in Bootstrap scrollspy function -->

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
```

Menu HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse  header-transparent">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll logo no-margin" href="#page-top"><img src="images/logo-uk.png"></a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="page-scroll nav-link" href="#page-top">HOME </a>
        </li>


        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="page-scroll nav-link" href="#frames"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="page-scroll nav-link" href="ppgtrikes.php"></a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          STORE
        </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="page-scroll nav-link" href="#engines">
              <font color="#000000"></font>
            </a>
            <a class="page-scroll nav-link" href="#harnesses">
              <font color="#000000"></font>
              </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="page-scroll nav-link" href="#contact"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of Container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 Bootstrap `nav`s, one inside the other.

**UPDATED**

In this file http://www.evoaviation.co.uk/js/custom.js you have part of code at the beginning

```
//Auto Close Responsive Navbar on Click
    function close_toggle() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            $('.navbar-collapse a').on('click', function () {
                $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.navbar .navbar-inverse a').off('click');
        }
    }
```

Replace it with following

```
//Auto Close Responsive Navbar on Click
    function close_toggle() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            // checking if there is no 'data-toggle' in <a>
            $('.navbar-collapse a:not([data-toggle])').on('click', function () {
                $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.navbar .navbar-inverse a').off('click');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Seems like it is still not working. I removed the data-target from the body tag and added the jQuery at the end of the page. Was it done correctly?

Comment: Sorry about the first try. Rollback a bit please. You can bring back `data-target=".navbar"` in `body`. Remove my last jQuery code and see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time! Works like a charm!